# How can I find the unique combinations based on two columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to find the unique entries in my dataframe using column `ID` and `Genus`.  I do not need to find unique values from column `Count`.  My dataframe is structured like this:

```
ID    Genus    Count
A     Genus1   4
A     Genus18  265
A     Genus28  1
A     Genus2   900
B     Genus1   85
B     Genus18  9
B     Genus28  24
B     Genus2   6
B     Genus3000 152
```

The resulting dataframe would have only

```
ID     Genus    Count
B      Genus3000  152
```

In it because this row is unique by ID and Genus.

I have tidyverse loaded but have had trouble trying to get the result I need.  I tried using distinct() but continue to get back all data from the input as output.

I have tried the following:

```
uniquedata <- mydata %>% distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
uniquedata <- mydata %>% group_by(ID, Genus) %>% distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
uniquedata <- mydata %>% distinct(ID, Genus, .keep_all = TRUE)
uniquedata <- mydata %>% distinct()
```

What should I use to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given data set, it is enough to check the column "Genus" for values appearing twice and then to remove the corresponding rows from the dataframe.

```
df %>% count(Genus) -> countGenus
filter(df, Genus %in% filter(countGenus,n==1)$Genus)
```

Comment: That made sense but unfortunately every thing gets the value 1, thus nothing is removed.

Comment: @aminards What do you mean by "every thing gets the value 1"? I tried the code and got the correct result

Comment: I suppose I have to accept that I have no unique values!

Answer (score 3):

We could use `add_count` in combination with `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    add_count(Genus) %>% 
    filter(n == 1) %>% 
    select(ID, Genus, Count)
```

Output:

```
  ID    Genus     Count
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 B     Genus3000   152
```